# How concatenate string with value in recharts - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I want to concatenate "%" with the value on `barchart` when values show on top of the bars.

How to do that ?

```
 <ResponsiveContainer width="99%" aspect={4}>
      <BarChart data={chartData} margin={{ top: 0, left: -30, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
        <Bar dataKey='hum' name="Humidity" barSize={15} fill='rgba(0, 60, 255, 0.6)' unit=" %" >
        <LabelList dataKey="hum" position="top" />
        </Bar>
        <CartesianGrid stroke="#ccc" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
        <XAxis dataKey="date" tick={{ fontSize: 12, fill: 'black' }} tickFormatter={(unixTime) => moment(unixTime).format('DD.MM - HHч.')} interval={1} />
        <YAxis tick={{ fontSize: 12, fill: 'black' }} />
        <Tooltip />
      </BarChart>
 </ResponsiveContainer>
```

[image: barchart]

I return data like this:

```
formatData = (data) =>
data.map(({ dt_txt, main, pop }) => ({
  // date -> Can be used as dataKey for XAxis
  //Further you can format the date as per your need
  date: dt_txt,
  // temp -> Can be used as dataKey for Line
  temp: main.temp,
  hum: main.humidity,
  rain:  pop
}));
```

I want to concatenate "%" to hum property and display the values on the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving "unit" attribute in YAxis, like this
<YAxis tick={{ fontSize: 12, fill: 'black' }} unit="%"/>

Edit:
Try changing LabelList tag like this.

```
<LabelList dataKey="hum" position="top" content={renderLabel} />
```

and add the below functional react component in your code.

```
const renderLabel= ({value}) => {

  return (
    <span>{ value + '%'}</span>
  );
};
```

Comment: This is good idea for YAxis but I want to show "%" with every value on the top..

Comment: As per the document, you can add content={renderLabel} in the LabelList tag, where renderLabel is your react component which should return value concatenated with %.

Comment: I update my qeustion, can you check.. I'm new in react and really want to get example how to do that.. if it's possible